# Induction Proof using factorials

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Recall that for $n \in N$, $n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdots n$.

Prove the following for each $n \in N$:

$$\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{4!} + \cdots + \frac{n}{(n+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

I understand how to do the proof, but in the inductive step I am facing some difficulty proving the left-hand side is equivalent to the right-hand side.To be direct I am facing some difficulty with the algebra required to make LHS = RHS.

Here is what I have done so far:

1) Base Case

$n = 1$

LHS:

$1/2$

and RHS is $1/2$ $\checkmark$

2) Inductive Step

For $k \geq 1$, Assume $n = k$

$$\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{4!} + \cdots + \frac{k}{(k+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$

$$n = k + 1$$

$$\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{4!} + \cdots + \frac{n}{(n+1)!} + \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

$$\implies 1-\frac{1}{(k+1)!} + \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(k+2)!}$$

Here is  where i do not know how to make the LHS = RHS.

Comment: You can ignore the 1, since it's the same on both sides. Next you need to take the LHS and add them up! Hint: multiply top and bottom of each to make the denominator of both $(k+2)!$

Comment: Can you please show me I have tried that before but don't seem to get a valid solution.

Comment: $1/(k+1)! = (k+2)/(k+2)!$

Comment: You were supposed to add  (k+1)/(k+2)! And simplify but you just added on the LHS and not RHS

Comment: can you fix the proof? @DOCTORNGILAZIBANDAJOSHUA

Comment: 1−1/(k+1)!+(k+1)/(k+2)!=(1-1/(k+1)!)[1-(k+1)/(k+2)]=1-1/(k+2)! Sorry my text has developed some faulty but I hope this is helpful

Comment: $S_{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=1-\frac{(n+1)-(n+2)}{(n+2)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}=1-\frac{1}{((n+1)+1)!}$ Therefore if the formula is correcy for n it is also true for n+1

Comment: Oh, thank you I know see where I have gone wrong. I added the fractional of k+2 lol. Thank you @Curious.

Comment: This is not the right way to organize a proof.  The first inequality above should be identified as something you're trying to prove, not something from which you are deducing something else.  The arrow, meaning "if, then" points in the wrong direction. Any honest course on writing proofs in mathematics would put great emphasis on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}$$
Note that to simplify this we need a common denominator. Let it be $(k+2)!$. Recall that $(k+1)! = (k+1)(k)(k-1)(k-2) \cdots$ So to get a $(k+2)!$ in the denominator of the fraction we must multiply the numerator and denominator by $k+2$ and get:
\begin{align*}
1-\frac{k+2}{(k+2)!} + \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!} &=1-(\frac{k+2}{(k+2)!} - \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}) \\
&=1-(\frac{k+2-k-1}{(k+2)!}) \\
&= 1-\frac{1}{(k+2)!} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we have to show that $$\frac{(k+1)}{(k+2)!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}=-\frac{1}{(k+2)!}$$ this is true since $$\frac{(k+1)}{(k+1)!(k+2)}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\left(\frac{k+1}{k+2}-1\right)=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\left(\frac{k+1-k-2}{k+2)}\right)=-\frac{1}{(k+1)!(k+2)}=-\frac{1}{(k+2)!}$$

Comment: What happened to the 1?

Comment: the $1$ was subtracted on both sides of the equation, is this a problem?

Comment: @Zero it just got subtracted from both sides of the equation.

Comment: Yes, I understand this now. Thank You.

Comment: don't forget the "downvoting"

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1,2,3$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2!}&=&\frac12=1-\frac12=1-\frac{1}{2!}\\
\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}&=&1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac13=1-\frac16=1-\frac{1}{3!}\\
\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{3}{4!}&=&1-\frac16+\frac{1}{8}=1-\frac{1}{24}=1-\frac{1}{4!}.
\end{eqnarray}
If we assume that up to $n=3$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}.
$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}&=&\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\\
&=&1-\frac{n+2-(n+1)}{(n+2)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}.
\end{eqnarray}